Linked Service Error after CICD in Azure Data Factory
After performing CICD from dev to qa of ADF, all other resources are in place but linked service didnot setup properly with the following error

The data factory Data-Factory-Ds-qa has no MI provisioned. Please update the data factory following: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity#generate-service-identity-using-powershell
The managed identity of entity data-factory-Ds-qa  was not found.

What does this error mean ? and how to resolve it .
Screenshot attached of LS connection.


Hi there, May I know if you have been using Azure Data Factory pipeline or Azure DevOps pipeline for CI/CD? Thx.

Hi . I am using Azure Devops pipeline for CICD

Thanks for the reply. Assuming your Azure DevOps pipeline was using ARM json templates to deploy ADF entities from dev to qa,  there should be no error during deployment, right? Have you tested to deploy the same templates via Azure Portal or Azure CLI to see if the issue is reproducible? It is helpful for us to narrow down the cause of the issue. Thx.

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT.
I have successfully deployed from dev to qa. In Adf-qa, all the linked services and pipelines are pushed. However, After I make connection to Git on new branch say qa-branch. Here , The linked services ain't coming up.
what could have went wrong?

So, the issue was irrelevant to the AzureKeyVault1 link service in your screenshot, right? From the error message itself, it seemed your qa ADF instance hadn't enabled Managed Identity. May I know if your dev and qa environments are two ADF instances? If yes, you may navigate to the qa ADF resource under your Azure Subscription in Azure Portal -> select the Settings section and Managed identities blade  -> check if the System assgined managed identity status is turned On.

Hi @Rudra, Hope you had a relaxing weekend. Have you got a chance to check my answer below to enable system assigned MI and may I know if can help resolve our issue in this post? Thx.

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT. I tried your approach. However, There is no option of SQL or Managed Instance Authentication in the drop down of Authentication type in my ADF linked service of Azure SQL db

Hi @Rudra, Have you enabled the MI feature for your ADF resource through Azur Portal as suggested in my answer? The issue was not related to the authentication type or other linked service types. Anyway, I have updated the answer with a reproducible sample of SQL server linked service not Azure SQL Database this time. Please enable MI first and then test the connection. Good luck and cheers.

Yes. I have enabled MI feauture

So you enabled MI but the error still exists? Were you modifying the correct ADF instance?

If possible, please share your qa instance MI settings in the original post with the error after the operation. Thx.

Update
The issue was irrelevant to which type of linked service type was selected. I could reproduce the issue by disabling the Managed identities (MI) feature for the Azure Data Factory resource, which resulted in the lack of service principal to authenticate access to Azure Key Vault secrets on behalf of the SQL server linked service. Hence even given the linked service type of SQL Server, the issue was also reproducible, when the Azure Data Factory Instance was not enabled with MI.

Please enable the MI feature for your qa instance by navigating to this Azure Data Factory resource under your subscription in Azure Portal following the steps in the image below.

Since it will generate a new service principal (system assigned MI) in your AAD, please also grant the MI with the required permission according to your need to retrieve secrets from the Azure Key Vault.

Once the above steps were completed, the linked service of SQL server was able to authenticate against the system assigned MI to access the Azure Key Vault and proceed to list secrets with different versions.


I could only reproduce the issue when the System Assigned managed identity of the target ADF instance was disabled. After the ARM template deployment via Azure DevOps pipeline completed successfully, I could see the entities like linked services, pipelines and triggers were published. However, when clicking on the Test connection button of my linked service of AzureSqlDatabase1, I encountered the error in the screenshot below.

To fix the issue, I navigated to the target ADF resource under my subscription in Azure Portal and enabled the System assigned managed Identity for it. Since it will create a new enterprise app in your AAD, please grant the new service principle with required permissions to access your linked services.

